# Return value conditional on characters

Tags: r, dplyr

I am dealing with a dataset that looks something like this

```
Year   Column1     
2000   yes no    
2001   yes yes    
2002   yes       
2003   N/A yes   
2004   N/A N/A   
2005   no no
```

As you can see, there are multiple and different strings within one cell. I want to create two new columns in which I have numeric values giving me information about Column1. My end product might look like this

```
Year   Column1   any_yes   yes_count   
2000   yes no    1          1
2001   yes yes   1          2
2002   yes       1          1
2003   N/A yes   1          1
2004   N/A N/A   0          0
2005   no no     0          0
```

Where "any_yes" checks whether the cell in Column1 contains a "yes" and returns 1/0. And where "yes_count" counts the number of "yes" in the cell in Column1 and returns the count. My best guess for any_yes would be something like this if I were dealing with numbers:

```
mydata1 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(any_yes = ifelse(Column1 = "yes", 1, 0)
```

Since I'm not dealing with numbers, I'm not sure how it works. I also don't know how to make the yes_count happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_count` (from `stringr`) and `grep` to do this.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(any_yes = +(grepl("yes", Column1)),
             yes_count = str_count(Column1, "yes"))
#    Year Column1 any_yes yes_count
#1 2000  yes no       1         1
#2 2001 yes yes       1         2
#3 2002     yes       1         1
#4 2003 N/A yes       1         1
#5 2004 N/A N/A       0         0
#6 2005   no no       0         0
```

---

We can also get the output without the `dplyr`

```
transform(df, any_yes = +(grepl("yes", Column1)),
              yes_count = str_count(Column1, "yes"))
```

Or without using any packages

```
within(df, {any_yes <- +(grepl("yes", Column1))
              yes_count <-  lengths(gregexpr("yes", Column1))* any_yes})
#   Year Column1 yes_count any_yes
#1 2000  yes no         1       1
#2 2001 yes yes         2       1
#3 2002     yes         1       1
#4 2003 N/A yes         1       1
#5 2004 N/A N/A         0       0
#6 2005   no no         0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `dplyr`.

Splitting the `column1` by spaces and finding the occurrences of `yes` for every list using `lapply`. If `yes_count` is greater than 1 then `any_yes` should be 1 else 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
mutate(yes_count=unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$Column1, " "),function(x)sum(grepl("yes", x))))
       ,any_yes = as.numeric(yes_count > 0))


#Year   Column1 yes_count any_yes
#1 2000  yes no         1       1
#2 2001 yes yes         2       1
#3 2002     yes         1       1
#4 2003 N/A yes         1       1
#5 2004 N/A N/A         0       0
#6 2005   no no         0       0
```